# FR2553560 was lapsed for what reason?

Tags: legal

The France patent [FR2553560](https://patents.google.com/patent/FR2553560A1/en?oq=FR2553560) was lapsed in 1998, as notification of lapse. The patent is valuable.
 I think it is used in MOX plant. I would like to know the reason of lapse of the valuable patent. How can I do that?

Comment: It should be noted that the questioner is very likely the same Akihiko Inoue listed as an inventor on the cited patent. It seems Mr. Inoue has an extensive list of patents to his name.

Comment: I have to know the detail of the lapse of France version FR2553560 rather than the Japanese version because the Japanese version was maintained to the lifetime.

Comment: As far as I can see, your only option is to contact the assignee.

Comment: I have already contacted with the assignee. They, however do not respond to my question.

Comment: I suspect that the registration of Japanese version of the patent was transferred to AREVA Japan from assignee JAERI and maintained during the lifetime of the patent. French version of the patent was lapsed due to the nonpayment of patent fee on the basis of the contract beteween JAERI and AREVA

Answer (score 1):

Short of asking the assignee of the patent: [Japan Atomic Energy Research Institute](https://www.jaea.go.jp/jaeri/english/index.html), there is no way to know why they allowed the patent to lapse. Generally the reason for allowing a patent to lapse is that the patent owner no longer feels the patent fees are justified by the income or protection derived by the patent. Perhaps no one in France was "dissolving plutonium dioxide or a mixed oxide of uranium and plutonium" using the described method after 1998? It should be noted that the patent would have expired anyway on October 12th, 2003.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You are right on the basis of the facts about the lapse of this patent. However, I believe that the patent was valuable until lapsed. There is no reason for nonpayment of patent fee. The assignee, JAERI reject display of the reason of the lapse for the patent. The MOX fuel prepared by this method, dissolving PuO2 in nitric acid, exists now in Takahama nuclear reactor of Japan.

Comment: @AkihikoInoue As far as I could tell, the Japanese equivalent patent didn’t lapse.

Comment: The Japanse equivalent patent was lapsed in 1997 April before the lapse of France patent FR2553560

Comment: MOX fuel is prepared by French company AREVA

Comment: @AkihikoInoue I have no knowledge of this field. It might be that AREVA already had a contract with JAERI so that maintaining the French patent was not necessary.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable information. Where is the source of that information?

Comment: @AkihikoInoue For European patents, https://worldwide.espacenet.com/?locale=en_EP is the site to get specifics on patent status. For Japanese patents try https://www.jpo.go.jp. If the answer suits you it would be nice if you accept it by clicking on the check mark.

Comment: I can not get the specifics on the Japanese version of the patent FR2553560 in the site jpo.go.jp. Is it possible to get the information abroad?

Comment: @AkihikoInoue I know very little about searching for details on Japanese patents. For sure it would have to be expired by now. You could post as a new question on this site. I'm sure someone could help you.